# How would we define a set that contains itself within a knowledge ontology?

Tags: knowledge-representation, ontology

How would we define a set that contains itself within a knowledge ontology?

I am thinking that *set membership* would probably inherit from a generic base class of *total containment* from which both *physical containment* and *conceptual containment* are derived.

- total containment

  - physical containment
  - conceptual containment

    - set containment

Comment: Hi Polcott! Your question isn't completely clear to me. You say "I am thinking that set membership would probably inherit from a generic base class of total containment", but then you show that "set containment" (which I think is a synonym for "set membership") derives from "conceptual containment". Can you clarify this? Furthermore, have a look at [Russel's paradox](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/253818/168764), which is at least remotely related to this question.

Comment: @nbro I am trying to piece together all humans concepts exactly how they already naturally fit together. I used the term [conceptual containment] as a more generic concept than [set containment].  [Members of a family] may be construed as an example of conceptual containment.